An attempt to show that any morphism between function fields is induced by a dominant rational map.
Let $X,Y$ be irreducible quasi-projective varieties. I'm trying to prove that every field extension $\Phi:k(Y)\rightarrow k(X)$ is induced by a dominant rational map $\phi:X\rightarrow Y$. (I am following the definitions in Shavalievich's book Basic Algebraic Geometry.)
My attempt:
Choose $y_k\notin \mathbb{I}(Y)$, define:
$$ \varphi:=(\Phi\left(\frac{y_0}{y_k}\right):\dots: \Phi\left(\frac{y_m}{y_k}\right))$$
$\varphi:X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^m$ should be the rational map such that $\varphi^*=\Phi$.
Now I want to show $\varphi$ maps $X$ to $Y$, where I get stuck. I can only show that for any $x\in U$ with $U$ the domain of definition, $\varphi(x)\in \overline{Y}$, by picking any $h\in \mathbb{I}(Y)$ and:
$$\begin{aligned}
&h(\frac{y_0}{y_k},\dots,\frac{y_m}{y_k})=\frac{h(y_0,\dots,y_m)}{(y_k)^d}=0 \quad \mbox{in 
} \ k(Y)\\
\Rightarrow &\Phi\left( h(\frac{y_0}{y_k},\dots,\frac{y_m}{y_k})\right)=0 \quad \mbox{in} \ k(X)\\
\Rightarrow &h\left( \Phi\left(\frac{y_0}{y_k}\right),\dots,\Phi\left(\frac{y_m}{y_k} \right)\right)=0 \quad \mbox{in} \ k(X)\\
\Rightarrow &h(\varphi(x))=0 \quad \forall x\in U
\end{aligned} $$
hence $\varphi(x)\in \mathbb{V}(\mathbb{I}(Y))=\overline{Y}$.
So can we deduce $\varphi(x)\in Y$ for some $x\in U$ from here? Or are there any other ways to show this? (I wish to find a proof in line with the definitions in Shavalievich's book)
Thank you for your help!
